# how do i use an emoji in a marketing cloud subject line

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to add an emoji in a subject line, the unicode value is `&x1F470;`

Currently I'm creating in AMPscript:

```
set @subjectline = "&x1F470; Bridal looks!"
```

But the emoji code keeps showing up as just the code.

Answer (score 4):

I just tested the following `=?utf-8?Q?=F0=9F=91=B0?=` and it worked for bride with veil (in gmail), which I got the values from this [website](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

[image: gmail emoji]

I also just used the emoji keyboard and inserted one into the subject line and it also worked in gmail
[image: emoji keyboard]
[image]

Use the emoji option from your computer.

Access the Mac emoji keyboard - Press Command ⌘ + Control + Space bar

Access the Windows 8 or Windows 10 emoji keyboard - Click the keyboard icon in the lower-right of the screen, then click the smiley face on the on-screen keyboard.